# Convert spaces in title field?

Tags: expressionengine

How can I output the title field with "%20" between each word? My mailto link is not validating because of the spaces, like:

```
mailto:?subject=My Title
```

I need:

```
mailto:?subject=My%20Title
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is "URL encode" the title (that is, you need to convert any invalid chars to percent encoding, spaces aren't the only problem).

This plugin on Devot:ee sounds like it should do just the trick: [URL Encode](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-encode)